# Persistence.xml for JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I have a client and server setup to run with JBoss AS 7.1.1 and I have a question about my persistence.xml. Currently it looks like this:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="GrahamsProj">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WorkCenterDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have persistence.xml in the META-INF folder of my server. I must be missing some properties though because I'm getting this error when I try to query the database I'm connected to.

```
11:35:07,840 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014134: 
EJB Invocation failed on component GrahamsProjBean for method public abstract 
void grahamsprojserver.session.interfaces.GrahamsProjBeanRemote.test(): javax.ejb.EJB
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
Schemas is not mapped [FROM Schemas s]
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to include all your model classes in persistence.xml. example:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="GrahamsProj">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WorkCenterDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>your.class.model.Example</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to update the hibernate.dialect property too. In your example you are using "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" and you use Oracle drivers, e.g. "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". If you are using Oracle database, you need to update hibernate dialect, e.g. "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect".

Here's your updated code:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="GrahamsProj">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WorkCenterDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>your.class.model.Example</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```